# Package pythonimmediate

Tags: python

I'm trying to load and use the package [pythonimmediate](https://ctan.org/pkg/pythonimmediate) but I'm facing difficulties in identifying what's going wrong. I had python 3.7 installed through Anaconda distribution. It seems that the package needs more recent version and I updated it to python 3.9. I also had to make python3 points to python command. But now I get the following:

```
! Package pythonimmediate Error: Cannot read line!

Type  to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.123   }
        
?
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pythonimmediate\pythonimmediate_script_textopy.py", line 60, in  connection=Client(address) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 507, in Client
c = SocketClient(address) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 635, in SocketClient s.connect(address) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée
```

Moreover the log file is not generated.
Does someone know what is going on and what I can do in order to make it works?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 0.3.0, I tested it to be working on MikTeX with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tlanalysispatch}  % I need this one because my LaTeX3 version is too old
\usepackage[python-executable=python,args={--naive-flush}]{pythonimmediate}
\begin{document}

456

\pyc{from pythonimmediate import*;print_TeX(123)}

\begin{pycode}
print_TeX(123)
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

Download from PyPI. You would need to update the sty file as well. (currently not yet published to CTAN)

`--naive-flush` is extremely slow. If you switch to LuaLaTeX then you don't need that flag.

---

**Old answer:**

I tried running the code on Windows, and encounter a number of issues:

- My version of MikTeX is a bit old so it has a bug (see https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/main/l3kernel/CHANGELOG.md#2022-04-10), which breaks a dependent package. (fixed)
- Windows encoding is not UTF8 by default. (fixed)
- the process that writes to TeX have stderr hidden, which makes it a bit more difficult to debug. (not a big deal)
- If something hogs the network socket, it will cause the network error message shown in the question (fixed in latest version, see below).
- **MikTeX does not flush the output after writing** (even when it's written to a pipe).
- TeX will not close the pipe, and the package tries to read one additional line from TeX as a sanity-check, which hangs the program. (not a big deal, can be fixed)

The highlighted issue is the hardest to fix, I'll fix it hopefully soon. (by using Lua to flush whenever possible, and when it's not possible, write arbitrary 4096 bytes to the file which forces it to flush)

For now, maybe TeX live would work better? (I didn't test)

By the way, it looks like you haven't used the latest version of the package. Upgrade to the latest version 0.1.0 (available on CTAN).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine with the latest versions of files. I look forward to seeing how it develops in the future. Thanks